# Load Testing for Django Application

Tags: django, load-testing, stress-testing

I have been looking for a tool to load test my django application. I was wondering if there is go to one for django web applications. I am required to login and place various requests to the site as multiple users and see how the site scales with traffic.

I have come across the following framweworks:

- Seige
- JMeter
- Funkload

I was wondering if the community had any opinions on which is best, and fit together best with the django web application.

I welcome suggestions to any that I haven't mentioned as well.

Please and thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to use javascript, and aren't looking to test your web server, I'm a huge fan of mechanize for this exact reason. spawn off several instances of mechanize that traverse your site, and you can get a very good idea of where your performance issues lie.

That said, if you do need javascript for anything, mechanize will not work as it has no ability to handle javascript. In this case you need to use selenium or webdriver. I've recently combined selenium with nunit for extremely great success. you can run several selenium instances and use selenium-rc to remotely track/control them. If you have some cash, browsermob does a fantastic job of this for you.

If you need to test your web server, look no further than apache bench.

Edit: This is my preferred approach. JMeter is very cool, but I found it a pain to use and an eyesore. YMMV though.